# Mysql: OperationalError at / (1054, "Unknown column '' in 'field list'")

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have made all of my migrations with these commands successfully.

```
python manage.py makemigrations senty
python manage.py migrate
```

I end up with this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/~/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
  return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/Users/~/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 71, in execute
  return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
File "/Users/~/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 250, in execute
  self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
File "/Users/~/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 50, in defaulterrorhandler
  raise errorvalue
File "/Users/~/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 247, in execute
  res = self._query(query)
File "/Users/~/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 411, in _query
  rowcount = self._do_query(q)
File "/Users/~/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 374, in _do_query
  db.query(q)
File "/Users/~/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 277, in query
  _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'senty_score.points' in 'field list'")


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/~/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 35, in inner
  response = get_response(request)
File "/Users/~/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 128, in _get_response
  response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
File "/Users/~/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 126, in _get_response
  response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Users/~/apps/sentiment/senty/views.py", line 15, in index
  return render(request, 'index.html', context)
File "/Users/~/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py", line 36, in render
  content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
File "/Users/~/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 62, in render_to_string
  return template.render(context, request)
File "/Users/~/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 61, in render
  return self.template.render(context)
File "/Users/~/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 175, in render
  return self._render(context)
File "/Users/~/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 167, in _render
  return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/Users/~/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 943, in render
  bit = node.render_annotated(context)
File "/Users/~/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 910, in render_annotated
  return self.render(context)
File "/Users/~/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 168, in render
  len_values = len(values)
File "/Users/~/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 254, in __len__
  self._fetch_all()
File "/Users/~/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1179, in _fetch_all
  self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
File "/Users/~/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 54, in __iter__
  results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
File "/Users/~/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1064, in execute_sql
  cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/Users/~/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 100, in execute
  return super().execute(sql, params)
File "/Users/~/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 68, in execute
  return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
File "/Users/~/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
  return executor(sql, params, many, context)
File "/Users/~/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
  return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/Users/~/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
  raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
File "/Users/~/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
  return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/Users/~/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 71, in execute
  return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
File "/Users/~/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 250, in execute
  self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
File "/Users/~/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 50, in defaulterrorhandler
  raise errorvalue
File "/Users/~/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 247, in execute
  res = self._query(query)
File "/Users/~/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 411, in _query
  rowcount = self._do_query(q)
File "/Users/~/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 374, in _do_query
  db.query(q)
File "/Users/~/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 277, in query
  _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
 django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'senty_score.points' in 'field list'")
```

To me, it looks like "points" is right there in the class, and it migrated successfully. The most updated pycache has the correct version of the class as well, which was an error before. I wasn't getting an error on this until I changed points from a different function call.

Pretty inexperienced to mysql so this is a tough one. Do I have to manually add the column somehow?

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime
from decimal import Decimal

class score(models.Model):
    ticker = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    points = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=1)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
```

MakeMigrations Output:

```
$ python manage.py makemigrations senty
No changes detected in app 'senty'
```

Comment: `points` is already in DB table `score` ?

Comment: @SachinKukreja  Ah, it is not there, only id, ticker and created_at are there. What's the easiest way to add it, just create a new database somehow?

Comment: You can add the field in any table using `alter table <table_name> add <column_name> decimal(4, 1);`